# How to force a WebView to break long lines of text into multiple lines?

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently getting HTML from a website (a forum), modifying it, and displaying it in a WebView. Sometimes however, there are strings that are so long and don't have any characters that the WebView deems allowing of a line break, so the WebView stretches horizontally and introduces horizontal scrolling. I hate horizontal scrolling, and I want to force the WebView to wrap those lines down to a new line regardless of whether the WebView likes the character it's wrapping ahead of or not.

Note: I do want the WebView to still expand and scroll vertically.

Comment: did you fix this

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately. I eventually moved over to native Android views instead of a webview wrapper, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use below style for break all type of words.
**reference link** [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

```
 style="overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; -ms-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word; -ms-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; "
```

**Demo**

```
String html ="<html> <head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=0,initial-scale=1.0\"></head><body style=\"overflow-wrap: break-word; " +
                "word-wrap: break-word; -ms-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word; -ms-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; \">" +
                YourHtmlText +"</body></html>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8",
                "about:blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your webview

```
 myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:stopScrolling()");
```

Add this function in your index.html

```
function stopScrolling()
{
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
}
```